# Any way to customize "Success" label at "Projects" page?

Tags: teamcity

When Teamcity makes successful build, it outputs green "Success" label (or "Tests passed...").

Can I customize this label, for example, output environment variable there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can customise the build status message shown for completed builds using the TeamCity service messages. The TeamCity documentation describes in good detail the format for these messages, which just need to be outputted to stdout. Following is an example of the build status message:

```
##teamcity[buildStatus status='SUCCESS' text='{build.status.text} and some aftertext']
```

[Build Script Interaction with TeamCity documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildStatus)